# Is there a bug in method SET_DATA_ROW of class CL_SALV_TREE?

Tags: abap

I spotted some very strange behavior using hierarchical SALV (class `CL_SALV_TREE`).

If I use the `set_data_row` method directly after creating the node instance then I receive the correct hierarchy.

```
REPORT zzy.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main
        RAISING cx_salv_msg cx_salv_error.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA: lt_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t000.
    cl_salv_tree=>factory(
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_tree = DATA(lo_salv_tree)
      CHANGING
        t_table = lt_data
    ).

    DATA(lo_tree_settings) = lo_salv_tree->get_tree_settings( ).
    lo_tree_settings->set_hierarchy_header( `Hierarchy` ).
    lo_tree_settings->set_hierarchy_size( 30 ).

    DATA(lo_nodes) = lo_salv_tree->get_nodes( ).
    DATA(lo_root_node) = lo_nodes->add_node(
      related_node = space
      relationship = if_salv_c_node_relation=>last_child
      data_row = VALUE t000( mandt = '100' )
      collapsed_icon = '@3S\QStatus: Collapsed@'
      expanded_icon = '@3T\QStatus: Expanded@'
      row_style = if_salv_c_tree_style=>emphasized_positive
      text = '100'
    ).
    lo_root_node->set_data_row( VALUE t000( mandt = '100' ) ).
    lo_root_node->get_hierarchy_item( )->set_icon( '@0V\QOK@' ).

    DATA(lo_node1) = lo_nodes->add_node(
      related_node = lo_root_node->get_key( )
      relationship = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child
      text = '200'
    ).
    lo_node1->set_data_row( VALUE t000( mandt = '200' ) ).
    DATA(lo_node2) = lo_nodes->add_node(
      related_node = lo_node1->get_key( )
      relationship = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child
      text = '300'
    ).
    lo_node2->set_data_row( VALUE t000( mandt = '300' ) ).

    DATA(lo_node3) = lo_nodes->add_node(
      related_node = lo_node2->get_key( )
      relationship = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child
      text = '400'
    ).
    lo_node3->set_data_row( VALUE t000( mandt = '400' ) ).

    lo_salv_tree->display( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  TRY .
    lcl_main=>main( ).
  CATCH cx_salv_msg cx_salv_error.
    ASSERT 0 = 1.
  ENDTRY.
```

[image: Correct hierarchy]

However if I use `set_data_row` method at the end of my `main` method, then the result is totally unexpected.

```
REPORT zzy.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main
        RAISING cx_salv_msg cx_salv_error.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA: lt_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t000.
    cl_salv_tree=>factory(
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_tree = DATA(lo_salv_tree)
      CHANGING
        t_table = lt_data
    ).

    DATA(lo_tree_settings) = lo_salv_tree->get_tree_settings( ).
    lo_tree_settings->set_hierarchy_header( `Hierarchy` ).
    lo_tree_settings->set_hierarchy_size( 30 ).

    DATA(lo_nodes) = lo_salv_tree->get_nodes( ).
    DATA(lo_root_node) = lo_nodes->add_node(
      related_node = space
      relationship = if_salv_c_node_relation=>last_child
      data_row = VALUE t000( mandt = '100' )
      collapsed_icon = '@3S\QStatus: Collapsed@'
      expanded_icon = '@3T\QStatus: Expanded@'
      row_style = if_salv_c_tree_style=>emphasized_positive
      text = '100'
    ).
    lo_root_node->get_hierarchy_item( )->set_icon( '@0V\QOK@' ).

    DATA(lo_node1) = lo_nodes->add_node(
      related_node = lo_root_node->get_key( )
      relationship = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child
      text = '200'
    ).

    DATA(lo_node2) = lo_nodes->add_node(
      related_node = lo_node1->get_key( )
      relationship = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child
      text = '300'
    ).

    DATA(lo_node3) = lo_nodes->add_node(
      related_node = lo_node2->get_key( )
      relationship = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child
      text = '400'
    ).

    lo_root_node->set_data_row( VALUE t000( mandt = '100' ) ).
    lo_node1->set_data_row( VALUE t000( mandt = '200' ) ).
    lo_node2->set_data_row( VALUE t000( mandt = '300' ) ).
    lo_node3->set_data_row( VALUE t000( mandt = '400' ) ).

    lo_salv_tree->display( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  TRY .
    lcl_main=>main( ).
  CATCH cx_salv_msg cx_salv_error.
    ASSERT 0 = 1.
  ENDTRY.
```

[image: Incorrect hierarchy]

Is this a bug in this component? I could not find any documentation that would explain this strange behavior.

Comment: Excellent way of asking a question and providing a reproducible example!

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: @BryanCain SAP_BASIS and SAP_ABA are in the following version: Release 740, SP-Level 0006, Support Package SAPKB74006 and SAPKA74006 respectively.

Comment: We're on SP7, and I have recreated the bug, so not much help there.  Sorry.  Have you tried debugging the set_data_row method to see where the data is getting lost?

Comment: @BryanCain No, I have not debugged the method yet but it looks like I will have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling *set_data_row* method you overwrite all raw data, including child relations.

In the first example you always set *mandt* first, and add node later on. If you would do it the other way around, you would also get 'one level deep' tree.

Comment: Agreed. The [note 775100 - ALV OM Tree: Performance when creating nodes](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/775100) discourages the use of `SET_DATA_ROW`: "To improve performance, the node must be created entirely using the method CL_SALV_NODES->ADD_NODE, that is, after the call of the method no setter methods of the class CL_SALV_NODE or the class CL_SALV_ITEM, in particular the data should be set in ADD_NODE using the parameter DATA_ROW and not using the additional call of the method CL_SALV_NODE->SET_DATA_ROW." So, better use `add_node( ... data_row = VALUE t000( mandt = '100' ) )`!

Comment: Well, what if you do not know the data at the time of adding the node? The example in the question is actually some simplified version. I have run into this issue while building the tree parallel to calculate some values recursively. The tree was built top-down and the values were summed up bottom-up, so the actual sum to be added to the node was not yet known at the time of adding the node.